# AX Flush method - InventAging

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

We are using AX 2012 R3 and having a customization on Inventory Aging Report.
I have a problem after we customized the InventoryAging report datasource, we added a new View in main report view (`InventValueReportView`) to came up with our expected filter. However, after customizing the report source, the output always shows a negative value *(the amount value is correct, it just negate the amount)*. We tried to debug and get the query and create a Job to check if the output is negative. The does well and output the correct amount value (not negative value). We tried to drill down and debug the code and we end up in the lines on `InventAgingDP.Run` which calls the `inventAgingReportLinesDetail.flush();`. We are amazed on how the flush method behave. after calling the flash method, the `inventAgingReportLinesDetail` had now the report line data which negates the Line Amount.
Any idea on why the amount negates or how the flush method behaves?